# Find similar sales orders in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my first post.

I work at a manufacturing company and most of the products we are making are custom made.
We believe we can find some commonalities in the products we sale.

To do this, we need to analyze sales orders and compare them to all the sales orders in our system to find identical ones.

Here's an example in form of a SQL result:

[image]

etc...

```
+------------------------------+
| OrderId   ProductCode    Qty |
+------------------------------+
| SS1234    Widget1        1   |
| SS1234    Widget2        3   |
| SS1234    Widget3        1   |
+------------------------------+
```

I would like to find orders similar to SS1234, ie orders with the same products (widget1, widget2 and widget3) and the same quantities.

How do I do this in SQL Server 2008R2?
Thanks for your help!
Raf

Comment: Your edit made the question harder to read.  Please show us sample input and the output you expect, along with the logic behind that output.

Comment: So like a self join on productcode = productcode and qty = qty and orderid != orderid? Or how many "widgets" need to match?

Comment: I can see that you are looking to match exact quantities & part numbers. But in future you might want to extend this to look at similarity of the part numbers (colour, weight, etc). If you want a more flexible approach, try looking up cosine similarity

Comment: Put back the text table of order details that relates directly to question.

Comment: If another order had widets 1 2 3 and **widget4** would it qualify as "similar"?

Answer (score 0):

I won't be able to test this before I go to bed for the evening. This is an overly verbose approach, but I wanted to grind this out as quickly as possible so I tried to use structure / syntax that I know well, instead of trying to write more concise, efficient code that would require I lean on the documentation. Basically, we're counting the number of items in each order, selecting a pair of order ids every time we find two matching line items, then we count how many times an exact pair of order IDs appears. Use inner joins to filter out pairs that matched fewer times than there are products in the order.

```
WITH 
ProductCounts AS (
SELECT COUNT(OrderID) AS ProductCodesInOrder, OrderID
FROM Table
GROUP BY OrderID
), MatchingLineItems AS (
SELECT A.OrderID AS FirstOrderID, B.OrderID AS SecondOrderID
FROM Table AS A
INNER JOIN Table AS B
ON A.ProductCode = B.ProductCode AND A.Qty = B.Qty
ORDER BY FirstOrderID, SecondOrderID
), MatchTotals AS (
SELECT
COUNT(FirstOrderID) AS Matches, FirstOrderID, SecondOrderID
FROM MatchingLineItems
GROUP BY FirstOrderID, SecondOrderID
), FirstMatches AS (
SELECT MatchTotals.FirstOrderID, MatchTotals.SecondOrderID, MatchTotals.Matches
FROM MatchTotals
INNER JOIN ProductCounts
ON MatchTotals.FirstOrderID = ProductCounts.OrderID
WHERE MatchTotals.Matches = ProductCounts.ProductCodesInOrder
)
SELECT FirstMatches.FirstOrderID, FirstMatches.SecondOrderID
FROM FirstMatches
INNER JOIN ProductCounts
ON FirstMatches.SecondOrderID = ProductCounts.OrderID
WHERE FirstMatches.Matches = ProductCounts.ProductCodesInOrder
```

Answer (score 0):

**Setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE #ord (
  OrderId VARCHAR(20),
  ProductCode VARCHAR(40),  
  qty int
)
INSERT INTO #ord (OrderId, ProductCode, Qty)
VALUES
  ('SS1234','Widget1',1)
 ,('SS1234','Widget2',3)
 ,('SS1234','Widget3',1)

 ,('SS1234a','Widget1',1)
 ,('SS1234a','Widget2',3)
 ,('SS1234a','Widget3',1)

 ,('xSS1234','Widget1',1)
 ,('xSS1234','Widget2',3)
 ,('xSS1234','Widget3',1)
 ,('xSS1234','Widget4',1)

 ,('ySS1234','Widget1',10)
 ,('ySS1234','Widget2',3)
 ,('ySS1234','Widget3',1)

 ,('zSS1234','Widget2',3)
 ,('zSS1234','Widget3',1)
;
```

**Query:**

```
with CTE as (
    select distinct
       o.OrderID, ca.ProductString, ca.QtyString
    from #ord o
    cross apply (
        SELECT
            STUFF((
                  SELECT
                        ', ' + o2.ProductCode 
                  FROM #ord o2
                  WHERE o.OrderID = o2.OrderID
                  ORDER BY o2.ProductCode 
                  FOR XML PATH ('')
                  )
                 , 1, 1, '')
          , STUFF((
                  SELECT
                        ', ' + cast(o2.Qty as varchar)
                  FROM #ord o2
                  WHERE o.OrderID = o2.OrderID
                  ORDER BY o2.ProductCode 
                  FOR XML PATH ('')
                  )
                 , 1, 1, '')
        ) ca (ProductString, QtyString)
    )
select
    ProductString, QtyString, count(*) Num_Orders
from CTE
group by
    ProductString, QtyString
having 
    count(*) > 1
order by 
    Num_Orders DESC
  , ProductString
```

**Result:**

```
ProductString                QtyString   Num_Orders
Widget1, Widget2, Widget3    1, 3, 1     2
```

See: http://rextester.com/DJEN59714